# codigo no se ejecuta en orden

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

buenas. Tengo una duda. En el siguiente codigo requiero de un ID para poder llenar una datatable, el problema radica en que cuando mando a llamar ese ID, me aparece vacío, siendo que ya llene la variable con un valor. al imprimir las variables en la consola me di cuenta de que se la funcion que trae ese ID se ejecuta DESPUES de que necesito el ID, siendo que el orden está correcto.

Este es el script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("ID1: " + id1);
  console.log("ID2: " + id2);
});
```

Aqui estoy imprimiendo los 2 id, y efectivamente id1 tiene un valor(que ya le pasé desde otro script) y luego id2, que es el id que necesito, está vacio. hasta aquí todo bien. ahora voy y busco el id2:

```
function comprobar() {
  if (id2 == "") {

    $.post(
      "../../proceso/controlador.php?op=obtenerID2",
      {
        id1: id1,
      },
      function (data) {
        id2 = data;
        console.log("ID ACTUALIZADO: " + id2);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

ahora imprimo el valor:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("ID1: " + id1);
  console.log("ID2: " + id2);
  comprobar();
});
```

y esto es lo que me aparece:

```
ID1: 2         VM1659:2
ID2: 1         VM1659:3
```

todo bien, eso significa que ya tengo mi id2, y ahora puedo seguir trabajando.

ahora lleno la datatable:

```
function llenarTablas() {

  tabla = $("#tabla1").dataTable({
    bFilter: false,
    bInfo: false,
    bPaginate: false,

    ajax: {
      url: "../../proceso/controlador.php?op=tabla1",
      data: { id2: id2 },
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      error: function (e) {
        console.log(e.responseText);
      },
    },
  });
}
```

pero esto no me llena la tabla.
lo que hice para comprobar por que no se llenaba, primero imprimí el valir de `id2`:

```
function llenarTablas() {

  console.log(id2);
  tabla = $("#tabla1").dataTable({
    bFilter: false,
    bInfo: false,
    bPaginate: false,

    ajax: {
      url: "../../proceso/controlador.php?op=tabla1",
      data: { id2: id2 },
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      error: function (e) {
        console.log(e.responseText);
      },
    },
  });
}
```

y este fue el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver, se ejecuta primero el llenado de la datatable y luego se va y se busca el id2. y no se como evitar esto. alguien tiene alguna idea del por qué de este comportamiento?

cabe resaltar que mi `$(document).ready` está así:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("ID1: " + id1);
  console.log("ID2: " + id2);
  comprobar();
  llenarTablas();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un problema típico de la programación asíncrona. Cuando llamas a la función **comprobar()**, esta hace una llamada POST y continúa ejecutando el siguiente código, esto es, la llamada a **llenarTablas()**. Sin embargo el POST es asíncrono y no podemos saber cuándo devolverá el resultado, puede ser unos milisegundos después o pueden ser varios segundos si el servidor o la conexión van muy lento.

Hay varias formas de abordar este problema (async/await, promesas), pero una que se me ocurre, relativamente sencilla es la de usar un parámetro de tipo función, que se llame cuando se reciben los datos.

```
function comprobar(f: any) {  // <=== Parámetro que es una función
    if (id2 == "") {
        $.post(
            "../../proceso/controlador.php?op=obtenerID2",
            {
                id1: id1,
            },
            function (data) {
                id2 = data;
                console.log("ID ACTUALIZADO: " + id2);
                f();  // <=== Llamo a la función una vez recibidos los datos
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Y en el **ready** haces la llamada así

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ID1: " + id1);
    console.log("ID2: " + id2);
    comprobar( llenarTablas ); // <=== llenarTablas se llama después de que se reciben los datos
});
```

No obstante, te recomiendo que te mires la teoría sobre programación asíncrona, async/await y promesas